# -thingWithContentsOfFile: vs. NSPropertyListSerialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation

Is there any meaningful difference between `+dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` `+arrayWithContentsOfFile:` and `NSPropertyListSerialization` (combined with `NSData` or `NSStream`), assuming that I know the file is of a specific type (e.g. I don't need to deserialize an arbitrary property list)?

Of course, I'll need to create an `NSStream` or `NSData` object before using `NSPropertyListSerialization`, so the collection methods are a little more succinct. But if one is faster or preferable in any way, I'd rather use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy enough to test. Start with a short sample program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSURL *url = ...

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSLog(@"%@", dict);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the contents of our plist file, as we would expect. Now, we put a breakpoint on the first line and run it again. Once we get the lldb prompt, we type:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -r '.*NSPropertyListSerialization.*'
```

Then, click "Continue" to resume execution. Sure enough, we stop on a breakpoint:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff4f22a018 Foundation`+[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:]
    frame #1: 0x00007fff4f229bbf Foundation`+[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) newWithContentsOf:immutable:] + 158
    frame #2: 0x00007fff4f242fe9 Foundation`+[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:] + 45
    frame #3: 0x0000000100000e7d MyGreatProject`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeefbff6a0) at main.m:15
    frame #4: 0x00007fff75461015 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

So, from this, we can determine that `+dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:` simply calls through to `NSPropertyListSerialization` to do its dirty work. So in practice, it's reasonable to conclude that it doesn't matter which you use, although `NSPropertyListSerialization` offers more flexibility through its `options` parameter and error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant difference. `NSPropertyListSerialization` is just more customizable.

For an ordinary array or dictionary there is nothing wrong to use `...withContentsOf...`